# Error generating WSDL in Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, wsdl

I'm novice using Netbeans and I was trying to test how works WDSL generation.

I created a basic web service and when tried to generate the WDSL the following error occurs:

> Error starting wsgen: class com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool BUILD
>   FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

This is the code, very basic:

```
package ServiciosWeb;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "Cajero")
public class Cajero {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

I googled the error message but only could obtain obscure explanations, none of them aplicable to this. Any advice about the meaning of this message and how to avoid it?

Comment: Make sure you are using JDK not JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I think I found the answer to this problem. It looks like there is an error related with the version 8.2 of Netbeans.

Apparently the default setting of `ant` is incorrect and this causes that a space separator was missed in the invocation of `wsgen`. And this is what I think was causing the error.

Since I still don't know how to set up the IDE version of `ant`, I copied the wrong statement from the output window and once fixed the problem of the spaces, I executed it from the command line. Everything went well this time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and applied the same solution for NetBeans 8.2 on Windows 7.

I copied the wrong statement from the console, I put an space between "wsegn" and their argument, and it worked!

Wrong statement: **wsgen"C:\Program Files**
Corrected statement: **wsgen "C:\Program Files**

Comment: Where is the file that needs to be changed located?